# Diagnose alarm failure on HTC One / lollipop

Tags: android, genymotion

I am developing an alarm app which works on every device I've tried except an HTC One with Android lollipop. The app UI all works as expected, but when the alarm is due to ring, nothing happens, no sound and no "Stop" button.

Unfortunately the HTC one is not mine, so I only have infrequent and brief access to it, I can't connect it to my PC to view the logs. I have Genymotion, but it only has an emulation of an HTC One with Android 4.4. My alarm worked perfectly on that.
I've also tried  both an xperia Z and a galaxy SIII both with lollipop, and it worked fine on those. It also worked of a variety of other devices with earlier versions of android.

So I am hoping for some possible explanations, or some possible mechanisms for diagnosing the problem. Or perhaps some alternative device that is available in genymotion that has some key features in common with the HTC.

**EDIT:** FYI the phone was not rebooted between the setting of the alarm and the time for the alarm to ring. Indeed the test was just setting the alarm to go off in one minute.

**EDIT:** This app is actually an old unfinished project that I am resurrecting. I have been using the beta version as my own personal alarm (not just wake-up, but meetings on specific dates, and a count-down timer too). It has worked reliably for me for over a year without a problem, on a galaxy sII and sIII. The alarms remain active even after powering down and rebooting.

Comment: are you using a broadcast receiever

Comment: Yes, it does use a broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried cleaning the cache of the app?
I have had some similar experience on 4.4 with various apks not working properly and the simple solution was to clean the cache of the app

-Penina Mezei

Comment: @stephen: I disagree... I'm only after ideas, I do not expect a definitive answer. I don't think my problem is anything to do with the cache, but it is still a valid answer in my book.

Comment: @mick thank you for not getting rid of my answer. I just went for the simple, most obvious answer. however, I do not own a HTC One and I cannot help you with this specific phone issue. have you tried it on another HTC One? (maybe the problem is specific for the unit itself)

Comment: I haven't tried another HTC one. I only have four physical devices I can test on thoroughly and it works fine on all of them.